# How to get data from multiple tables using SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three Tables Administration with relation one-to-many with Telephone, Fax Tables:

`Administration : Id_Administration, Lib_Administration`

`Telephone: Id_Phone, Phone_Number, Id_Administration`

`Fax: Id_Fax, Fax_Number, Id_Administration`

Administration table contains:

```
Id_Administration Lib_Administration 
1                 adminstration1                                               
2                 adminstration2
```

Telephone table contains:

```
Id_Phone Phone_Number Id_Administration
1        0313131      1
2        0212121      1
3        0353535      2
4        0343434      2
```

Fax table contains:

```
Id_Fax  Fax_Number  Id_Administration
1       0323232     1
2       0363636     2
3       0373737     2
```

I want to make a query to show this result:

```
Id_Administration Lib_Administration Phone_Number Fax_Number
1                 adminstration1     0313131      0323232
                                     0212121      
2                 adminstration2     0353535      0363636
                                     0343434      0373737
```

I used this query

```
SELECT   Administration.Id_Administration, Administration.Lib_Administration,Telephone.Phone_Number, Fax.Fax_Number
FROM     ((Administration INNER JOIN
         Telephone ON Administration.Id_Administration = Telephone.Id_Administration) INNER JOIN
         Fax ON Administration.Id_Administration = Fax.Id_Administration)
```

But the result was iterated like this:

```
Id_Administration Lib_Administration Phone_Number Fax_Number
    1                 adminstration1     0313131      0323232
                                         0212121      0323232
    2                 adminstration2     0353535      0363636
                                         0343434      0363636
                                         0353535      0373737
                                         0343434      0373737
```

I used left join but i didn't get the right result, so where is the problem in my query?

Comment: Without sample data, it will be hard to help you.  In any case, I don't think an Access query generated either of your two outputs.  You should show us your actual output.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: This output based on that input doesn't look possible, since it looks order-based without a clear ordering column. Why would phone number _0313131_ be in the same row as fax number _0323232_, and phone number _0212121_ not have a fax number at all?

Comment: the administration can has one or more phone_number and one or more fax_number not necessary 2 phone and 2 fax

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but sometimes hard work to achieve our goal is not worth it. Are you trying to prepare a recordset for your form?
In this scenario I would have 2 subforms, for phone and fax numbers. No need to load all in one recordset.

Comment: No, i want to create an RDLC Report and this is the DataSet of the Tablix

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the original table structure works.  In the posted DDL you have administration-level granularity.  What you want to do is pair a phone number with a fax number- I would call this the office-level granularity.  What you can do is add another level of granularity by creating an Office table.  In the inserts, link each phone and fax number also to this office ID.  For the Select, join the phone and fax tables also to this Id_Office.  This should pair the phones by both Organization and Office to give the expected output.

For example if you include an Office table similar to below:

```
CREATE TABLE Administration (Id_Administration int, Lib_Administration varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Administration (Id_Administration, Lib_Administration) VALUES 
 (1, 'adminstration1'), (2, 'adminstration2')

CREATE TABLE Office(Id_Administration int, Id_Office int, Lib_Office varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Office (Id_Administration, Id_Office, Lib_Office) VALUES
 (1, 1, 'A1 Office 1'), (1, 2, 'A1 Office 2')
,(2, 1, 'A2 Office 2'), (2, 2, 'A2 Office 2')

CREATE TABLE Fax (Id_Fax int, Fax_Number char(7), Id_Administration int, Id_Office int)
INSERT INTO Fax (Id_Fax, Fax_Number, Id_Administration, Id_Office) VALUES
 (1, '0323232', 1, 1), (2, '0363636', 2, 1)
,(3, '0373737', 2, 2)

CREATE TABLE Telephone (Id_Phone int, Phone_Number char(7), Id_Administration int, Id_Office int)
INSERT INTO Telephone (Id_Phone, Phone_Number, Id_Administration, Id_Office) VALUES
 (1, '0313131', 1, 1)
,(2, '0212121', 1, 2)
,(3, '0353535', 2, 1)
,(4, '0343434', 2, 2)

SELECT A.Id_Administration, A.Lib_Administration, T.Phone_Number, COALESCE(F.Fax_Number, '') AS Fax_Number
  FROM Administration A LEFT JOIN Office O ON A.Id_Administration = O.Id_Administration
                         LEFT JOIN Fax F ON F.Id_Administration = A.Id_Administration AND F.Id_Office = O.Id_Office
                         LEFT JOIN Telephone T ON T.Id_Administration = A.Id_Administration AND T.Id_Office = O.Id_Office
```

This produces output:

```
Id_Administration   Lib_Administration  Phone_Number    Fax_Number
                1       adminstration1       0313131       0323232
                1       adminstration1       0212121
                2       adminstration2       0353535       0363636
                2       adminstration2       0343434       0373737
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27964/3/0